# Get Users with an attribute for each Group?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My models: `User`, `Group`, and `Membership`. Users can have many groups through memberships, and vice-versa. I want to create a tool for website admins that produces a large table with the following specification:

Every row represents a `user`,
Every column represents a `group`,
In each cell of the table there is a boolean indicating whether the `user` belongs to the `group`.

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to write a single SQL query that achieves it (i.e. `User.find_by_sql`)? If not, how else?

p.s. I actually need a bit more than this (I need two columns per group, the first one indicating membership, and the second one counting how many `meeting`s the `user` has attended in that `group`, but this involves the `Meeting` model, so I'll leave that for later.

Comment: The model `User` has many `Memberships`, and the model `Membership` has many `Groups`. Is that correct? Cause I am editing an answer to this.

Comment: In the first paragraph you said _user can have many groups_ but later you say _user belongs to group_. Try clearing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're asking about the backend methodology not the data visualization aspect most of what JuanM. said is correct. One thing I would recommend is avoid writing his 'get_groups' method and just set up a 'has many through' relationship between users in groups. To do so put

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

In your Users model and vice versa in your Groups model (assuming memberships 'belongs_to' both). Then you'll have a '.groups' method on any User instance and a '.users' method on any Group instance

Comment: @gdiazc Any chance I could get best answer on this? Would really like to be able to comment haha

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

1. Write a function that returns if the user belongs to a group passed by parameter. Get all the groups from a user. In your `user.rb` model you can add this method `get_groups` to retrieve all groups from the user and then a method `is_in(group)`. See code below:

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     #validations, some other stuff     
     has_many :memberships  

     #this method stores all the group-ids of the user in an array
     def get_groups

       myGroups = []

       memberships.each do |membership|
         membership.groups.each do |group|
           myGroups << group.id
         end
       end

       return myGroups

     end

     #this method receive a Group object and return true if the user belongs to that group
     def is_in(group)
       groups = get_groups
       return groups.include?(group.id)
     end
   ```
2. Then in your view or controller you can work as follow:

   ```
    #the columns of the table
    groups = Group.all

    #iterating all users
    User.all.each do |user|

      #each user has to see if it belongs to each group in the groups table
      groups.each do |group|

        #the boolean value you display in a cell
        value = user.is_in(group)

      end

    end
   ```